# ¿Cómo hacer referencia a una imagen en vista de Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Me encuentro trabajando en el framework `Yii2`, pero en mi vista no he encontrado la forma de llamar un recurso de `imagen` desde la carpeta `assets` que se encuentra en la `raíz` del `proyecto`.

Anteriormente en el framework `Codeigniter` usando la instrucción `base_url()."ruta/imagen.png"`, podía acccedr a mi carpeta de recursos `assets` que de igual manera se encontraba en la raíz del proyecto y en mis vistas llamaba las imagenes dinámicamente de la siguente manera:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/".array["nombre_imagen"] ?>">
```

Con el simple uso de `base_url()`, podía acceder a cualquier recurso.

Pero en `Yii2`, he intentado con:

```
<?= Html::img( Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'assets/AC.png', ['alt' => 'value'])?>
```

y no funciona, pero tampoco es lo que quiero hacer, ya que esta instrucción imprime un elemento `img`, yo lo que quiero, es poder hacer lo mismo que con `Codeigniter`, para poder acceder a cualquier recurso independientemente de si es o no una imagen.

De igual forma intenté almacenar lo que tiene `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl` en una variable para intentar replicar lo que busco, pero tampoco me funciona.

Solo me ha funcionado de esta manera:

```
<?= Html::img('@web/assets/box.png', ['alt'=>'some', 'class'=>'thing']);?>}
```

Pero me imprime todo el elemento `img`; como pueden ver, hice otra carpeta assets dentro de la carpeta `web`, ya que la que hice en la `raíz` del proyecto, no la reconoce, desconozco la razón.

La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguente (solo carpetas en las que hago enfasis):

```
proyecto
     assets
          imagen.png
     web
         assets
              imagen.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado una forma de solucionarlo, pero solamente al acceder directamente a la carpeta `web`, la cual ya viene integrada junto con el `framework`, pero si quisiera acceder a la carpeta `assets` que puse en la raíz del proyecto, no he podido.

Lo logré así:

```
<img src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').'/assets/'.array["nombre_imagen"]; ?>" alt="nombre">
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui acceder la carpeta assets dentro del proyecto de la siguiente forma.
con getAlias('@app/assets')

```
    $path2xml =  \Yii::getAlias('@app/assets/xml_DE.xml');  
    
    if ( file_exists($path2xml) ){
        echo $path2xml . '<br>';
        echo 'fue encontrado el archivo';
    }else {
        echo 'No existe archivo';
    } ;
    
    exit();

 // respueta del script:
      /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii2-rest-sifen/assets/xml_DE.xml
      fue encontrado el archivo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]